# Materialiui Paper api with close button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am implementing Paper from Material UI: https://mui.com/components/paper/

And here is the code I have written so far:

```
<Paper className="modal" elevation={3}>
    {..Content..}
</Paper>
```

The current UI makes it open a special pane which closes only when I click on area outside of it. I want to add a close button to close the Paper. Is it possible to add a custom onClose action on it?

Edit: Here is a codesandbox that I have replicated: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-surf-r1yz87?file=/src/App.js

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code missing if this closes when clicking outside of it. The functionality you're describing sounds closer to https://mui.com/components/dialogs/. We need more info to help you.

Comment: @Stanislas, I have added a sample Codesandbox to replicate the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paper is just a surface to render components on, it does not support any functionality. For this use case, a `state` variable can be used to hide and unhide the `Paper` component. You may make it a reusable component.

```
const [shouldShowPaper, setShouldShowPaper] = useState(true);
 ...
{
    shouldShowPaper && 
    <Paper elevation={props.elevation} style={{position: "relative"}}>
        <button 
            style={{position:"absolute", top: "10px", right: "10px"}}
            onClick={() => setShouldShowPaper(false)}
        >
            X
        </button>
        {props.children}
    </Paper>
}
```

You may toggle classes to show transitions instead of abrupt removal of the paper component.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to follow the same by having some slight modifications